# need help creating an input function with two parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been coding for about a month now and i just began working on functions. 
This function will prompt the user to enter an integer. If the number is lower than low or higher than high, it will output an error message to the user and then prompt again. Otherwise, it will return the number that the user typed.

Here is what i have so far

```
    getNumberInRange(x,y):
        counter = 0
        answer = 0

    while counter < y:
        answer = answer + x
        counter = counter + 1
        return answer
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Python 2.7 and 3 are not compatible. Please chose one.

Comment: im not sure how to create a function with two inout parameters that prompts a user for an integer if the number is lower than low or higher than high, it will output an error message to the user and then prompt again. Otherwise, it will return the number that the user typed. I've gone through every function chapter online and i can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach also..

```
def getNumberInRange( low,high ):
   n1 = int(input("Enter a number:"))
   if ((n1 < low) or (n1 > high)):
       print("Please enter the number between the range "+ str(low) +" and "+ str(high))
       getNumberInRange(10,100)
   else :
       print(n1)
       return;
getNumberInRange(10,100)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  def getNumberInRange(x,y):
      counter = 0
      answer = 0
      while counter < y:
         answer += x
         counter += 1
      return answer, counter

  print(getNumberInRange(10,20))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getNumberInRange(x,y):
   while True:
      a=int(input("Enter Number"))
      if not x < a < y:
         print("Invalid")
      else:
         return a
```

Try this.

> This function will prompt the user to enter an integer. If the number
>   is lower than low or higher than high, it will output an error message
>   to the user and then prompt again.

Hope this helps ***`:)`***

Comment: You don't need the `loop` flag; `return` will terminate the function, and `a<x or a>y` can be replaced with `not x < a < y`.

Comment: Thanks! Changed it